# Override MSSQL database Connection String in Yaml (Kubernetes)

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, environment-variables, .net-6.0

I have been trying this without any luck, I have a project written in .NET v6.0 and I need to deploy to multiple Kubernetes clusters, Each cluster has it's own database hosted on Azure. Using Azure CI/CD pipeline, I'm trying to override connection strings in `appsetting.json` to match the different Kubernetes clusters. However when I deploy this application it does not overwrite the connection strings set in the environmental variables. I have other environment variables set and they work just fine, I only have issues with `connectionstring`

My `appsetting.json`

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server= 192.168.2.68; database=TransactionLogs;user id=sa;password=exTened;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "TransferPay": "input value",
  "TransferPayConn": "input value"

}
```

looks like this

In my Yaml manifest I tried to override this value using environment variables like this

```
env:
  - name: Logging__LogLevel__Default
    value: Debug
  - name: Logging__LogLevel__Microsoft.AspNetCore
    value: Debug
  - name: TransferPay
    value: google.com
  - name: TransferPayConn
    value: yahoo.com
  - name: ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection
    valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: db-config
          key: database_uri
```

ConfigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db-config
  namespace: dev
data:
  database_uri: "Server= 192.168.2.68; database=TransactionLogs;user id=sa;password=exTened;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

Comment: Unless the program is coded to allow connection string overrides via environment variables you're going to need to modify the contents of the `appSettings.json` file. I don't think [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) can help you here. Have you considered overriding `ENTRYPOINT` with a custom script that updates the file before executing the intended program?

Comment: Aside... the JSON path you're trying to override in the sample is `ConnectionStrings.ConnStr`. If the program is even using the [Environment Variable Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#environment-variable-configuration-provider) then you'd need to set `ConnectionStrings__ConnStr` as opposed to `ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection` shown in your YAML.

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning i made a slight mistake in the post, But that has been corrected. I'm a bit confused because setting other environment variables works. Just issues with connectionstring, I'll look into the ENTRYPOINTS and implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out,

The issue was from the .Net Project, the Database model was missing `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`